# How to change the set of characters that are considered word characters in Mysql (Without recompiling)?

Tags: mysql, configuration, performance

I run a Mysql 5.0.26 (Myisam tables). To improve the search results, I am doing some fine tuning. I have noticed that the characters considered as word characters do not match the constraints of (Swiss-) French... and English too. :(

I would like to:

- ADD the character "-" in the "word character" list
- REMOVE the character "'" from the same list (This is a bug in the 5.0 branch only fixed in 5.1...)

I have seen in the documentation that I can use the macro true_word_char(). But the document is a little cryptic for me. :(

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

How can I do it?

Do I have to edit this also?

```
<charset name="latin1">
  <ctype>
    <map>00 20 20 20 20 20 ...... 02 02 02</map> 
  </ctype>
```

Is there any known bug/risk doing it?

I cannot recompile.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the part about editing the ture_word_char() macro would require a recompile.

so that leaves editing the XML file for that character set. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/character-arrays.html for a table of the values for each character. simply locate which value is - and ' and set them as appropriate for your application.